# dbplyr function equivalent to EXISTS in sql

Tags: r, postgresql, exists, dbi, dbplyr

Some time ago I did this question: [Speeding up PostgreSQL queries (Check if entry exists in another table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61462084/speeding-up-postgresql-queries-check-if-entry-exists-in-another-table/61462271#61462271)

But, since I'm working with `DBI` with `dbplyr` as backend, I'd like to know whats is the `dbplyr` function equivalent to `EXISTS` function from PostgreSQL.

For while, I'm performing the query using literal SQL sintaxe

```
myQuery <- 'SELECT "genomic_accession", 
       "assembly", 
       "product_accession", 
       "tmpcol", 
       ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM   "cachedb" c 
                 WHERE  c.product_accession IN ( pt.product_accession, pt.tmpcol 
                                               )) ) 
       AS CACHE, 
       ( EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                 FROM   "sbpdb" s 
                 WHERE  s.product_accession IN ( pt.product_accession, pt.tmpcol 
                                               )) ) 
       AS SBP 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   "pairtable2") pt; '
dbExecute(db, myQuery) -> tmp
```

Then, I tried to pass literal SQL instructions to mutate:

```
pairTable %>% 
  head(n=5000) %>%
  mutate(
    CACHE = sql('EXISTS( select 1 FROM "cacheDB" AS c 
                WHERE c.product_accession IN ( product_accession, tmpcol)  )' ),
    SBP = sql('EXISTS( select 1 FROM "SBPDB" AS s 
                WHERE s.product_accession IN ( product_accession, tmpcol)  )' )
  )
```

But this way, I don't know why I'm lacking all cases which are false, the comparison.
And I expect there is an implementation of this method in `dbplyr` or even some DBI method to this.

Thanks

Comment: Checking the `IN` conditions for both `product_accession` and `tmpcol` together seems like the hardest part of your question. How large are `cacheDB` and `SBPDB`? There is a much easier work-around if these are small (<20 rows).

Comment: @Simon.S.A. `cacheDB` has 90k lines, `SBPDB` has 500k, and the `pairTable` 36M rows.